# Why is clock synchronization on servers difficult?

Tags: azure, cloud, server, clock

See: [Clock synchronization quality on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138955/clock-synchronization-quality-on-windows-azure)

This is not meant as a rant, it is just curiosity.

- Is a computer really drifting more than a second in a single day? I can barely imagine that.
- Why not a sync every day to a time server. This should have minimal negative impact compared to the advantages of a (relative) consistent clock among servers.

My gut feeling would be that the biggest problem would be latency, but even that would be just a few ms after every sync. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe ask this on ServerFault? It's not a programming question.

Comment: Why do you think machines aren't syncing to a series of time servers? Why do you think a computer won't drift a second in a single day? Many protocols (e.g., Kerberos) are sensitive to drift, so synchronization does happen. Many hardware vendors recognize that accuracy in a computer clock isn't particularly important because computers will regularly resynchronize anyway, so computer clocks can have significant drift over human time scales.